# Is it possible for QtWidgets to select file from server?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using `QtWidgets` to select file folder. Here is how I do it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
open = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
root = open.getExistingDictionary('path_to_folder')
```

The question is I may need to select file folder from a server. Is it possible to configure something for `QtWidgets` to do so?

Comment: With "server" do you mean a local shared resource, or a remote server accessible through other protocols (http, ftp, etx)? Besides that, the correct function name is `getExistingDictionary`, and since you're using a static function, you don't need to create an intance of QFileDialog.

Comment: @musicamante I mean a ftp remote server. Does `QtWidgets` support that?

Comment: `QtWidgets` is only the *widget* module, the part responsible of displaying objects on screen, so the question is inaccurate. That said, have you checked the documentation about the other static methods, specifically [`getExistingDirectoryUrl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectoryUrl)? I never used it and I cannot check it right now, but if your system supports ftp access through the file native file dialog that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks very much. Your advice is important.